# What technology is 'Draw Something' using?

Tags: facebook, animation, mobile, platform

It looks like cross platform with flash?
Or is it html + javascript?

I am looking for a technology that support these features:
+ good animation (like draw something)
+ cross platform
+ communicate well with facebook/twitter
  - get friend list, send app invites etc

Comment: Which tehcnologies do you know already?

Comment: i know html + javascript, but not sure whether it's easy to create good animations

Comment: i also notice html5 canvas look a bit blur in iOS devices, not very sharp, any idea?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken they are using Adobe Air which makes it cross platform. I strongly advise against using that horrible technology. And yeah, html5 is not as "slick" as native apps.

Comment: What platform are you targeting for this? iOS, Andriod, Web, Desktop..?

Comment: targeting mobile platforms, iOS, Android, etc, cross platform